# How to detect in Linux an event when an expected window position appears when a window is dragged to one of the screen borders

Tags: c++, c, linux, xlib

How to programmatically detect in Linux via C/C++/Xlib an event when an expected window position appears when a window is dragged to one of the screen borders (such as shown in the picture).

[image]

Tried this method, but the message 'ConfigureNotify' does not come.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *dsp;
    Window wnd_root;
    dsp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    wnd_root = XRootWindow(dsp, 0);
    XSelectInput(dsp, wnd_root, StructureNotifyMask);

    while (true) {
        XEvent evn;
        XNextEvent(dsp, &evn);
        switch (evn.type) {
        case ClientMessage:
            g_print("Client Message\n");
            break;
        case ConfigureNotify:
            g_print("Configure Notify\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    XCloseDisplay(dsp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that is an event of some kind, looks to me like it's the window manager drawing a rectangle on the screen when it detects that you moved a window all the way to the border of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an X event, but a Window Manager event, typically called *"window snapping"*.

Your application can easily detect when it has happened, by monitoring [ConfigureNotify events](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/configure.html), but I do not know of any way to detect it before, when the Window Manager is still displaying the hint about it to the user.  (There could be Window Manager specific ways, but I do not recommend doing that kind of thing at all.)

For best User eXperience, do not try to catch and modify this kind of behaviour, because other applications don't do it either.  Instead, make sure your application window can be resized to any size the user wants, although you can set minimum, preferred, and maximum size for each window.  Typically, this means that instead of making your windows specific pixel sizes, you use the font size (or the size of some prototype text) as your guide, or do a form-like relative layout.

---

Consider the following example, **example.c**:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
// gcc -Wall -O2 $(pkg-config --cflags x11) example.c $(pkg-config --libs x11) -o example
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display *display;
    int      screen;
    Window   window;
    XEvent   event;
    Atom     wm_delete;
    long     counter = 0L;

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!display) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No display.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(display);
    window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display),
                                 0, 0, 320, 240,
                                 2, WhitePixel(display, screen),
                                 BlackPixel(display, screen));
    wm_delete = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", True);

    XSelectInput(display, window, ButtonPressMask | StructureNotifyMask);

    XMapWindow(display, window);

    XSetWMProtocols(display, window, &wm_delete, 1);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        switch (event.type) {

        case MapNotify:
            fprintf(stderr, "%ld. MapNotify\n", ++counter);
            break;

        case ReparentNotify:
            fprintf(stderr, "%ld. ReparentNotify\n", ++counter);
            break;

        case ConfigureNotify:
            fprintf(stderr, "%ld. ConfigureNotify: (%d, %d), width %d, height %d.\n",
                            ++counter,
                            event.xconfigure.x, event.xconfigure.y,
                            event.xconfigure.width, event.xconfigure.height);
            break;

        case ButtonPress:
            fprintf(stderr, "%ld. ButtonPress. Closing window.\n", ++counter);
            XCloseDisplay(display);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;

        case ClientMessage:
            if (event.xclient.data.l[0] == wm_delete) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%ld. ClientMessage: WM closed the window.\n", ++counter);
                XCloseDisplay(display);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "%ld. ClientMessage\n", ++counter);
            break;

        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%ld. Unknown event type (%d).\n", ++counter, event.type);
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a small (320x240) window, and describes the ConfigureNotify events that window receives to standard error.  Click on the window (or the window close button) to end the program.

Comment: I tried using 'ConfigureNotify' but for some reason this event does not come (added code in the description). Only event 'ClientMessage' comes.

Comment: @Helg1980: Your example code attempts to listen for events on the root window.  That is not being moved or snapped.  The ConfigureNotify event is sent to the window being manipulated.  See the example code I just added.  (When the window manager displays the possible snapping action to the user, no event is generated; only when the window is actually snapped, is a ConfigureNotify event generated, as I described in my answer.)

Comment: @Helg1980: If you want to find out when *any* window is dragged to a specified position, then you need to work with your window manager, WM, instead.  (You could technically poll, repeatedly checking the positions of all application windows, but that is very inefficient.  Working with the window manager is much more sensible and efficient.)